# Send messages to Kafka Topic from iOS

Tags: ios, apache-kafka

I have set up a multi broker Kafka cluster in my local server. I want to be able to send messages to the Kafka topics in this cluster from a iOS app.Is there any api available that will allow me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try [kafka rest proxy](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest), which support to send/consumer messages in rest style.